# Aggregate Locust test results runtime

Tags: python, locust

I have two apparantly similar tests in Locust, but one of them writes every call two the `web-gui`, while the other one aggregates the calls. I want both tests to do as the latter aka aggregate.

[image: Locust GUI]

This test does not aggregate the calls:

```
class LoadValues(FastHttpUser):
host = server_name

def _run_read_ts(self, series_list, resolution, start, end):
    TSIDs = ",".join(series_list)
    resp = self.client.get(f'/api/loadValues?tsIds={TSIDs}&resolution={resolution}'
                           f'&startUtc={set_from_date()}&endUtc={set_to_date()}',
                           headers={'X-API-KEY': 'AKjCg9hTcYQ='})

    print("Response status code:", resp.status_code)

@task
def test_get_ts_1(self):
    self._run_read_ts(random.sample(TSIDs, 1), 'PT15M', set_from_date(), set_to_date())
```

But this test do aggregate:

```
class SaveValuesUser(FastHttpUser):
host = server_name

# wait_time = between(10, 15)

@task(2)
def save_list_values(self):
    data_list = []

    # for i, (ts_id, ts_value) in enumerate(random.sample(TS_IDs.items(), random.randint(1, 25))):
    for i, (ts_id, ts_value) in enumerate(random.sample(TS_IDs.items(), 100)):
        data = get_data(ts_id, from_date, to_date, set_value())
        data_list.append(data)

    json_data = json.dumps(data_list, indent=2)
    self.save_values(json_data)

def save_values(self, json_data):
    print(type(json_data))
    print(json_data)
    # Make the PUT request with authentication:
    response = self.client.put("/api/SaveValues", data=json_data, headers=headers)
    # Check the response:
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("SaveValues successful!")
        print("Response:", response.json())
    else:
        print("SaveValues failed.")
        print("Response:", response.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Locust uses the URL as the Name it aggregates things under. Unique URL == unique stats. Notice that your `endUtc` URL parameter is different for each call, hence they're not being aggregated. You can override this behavior [using the `name` parameter](https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/api.html?#locust.clients.HttpSession.request) when making your calls.

```
resp = self.client.get(f'/api/loadValues?tsIds={TSIDs}&resolution={resolution}'
                       f'&startUtc={set_from_date()}&endUtc={set_to_date()}',
                       headers={'X-API-KEY': 'AKjCg9hTcYQ='}, name='api/loadValues')
```